# Lower Bound and approximation of Probability of hamming weight in $[n,n+\sqrt{n\pi}]$.

Tags: approximation, coding-theory

If the probability of $1$ is $p$ what is the probability that a length $2n-1$ random $0/1$ vector has weight in range $[n,n+\sqrt{n\pi}]$?

For $p=\frac12$ is it (with $\delta\rightarrow0+$) given by lower bound $\sum_{i=n}^{n+\sqrt{n\pi}} \frac{\binom{2n-1}{i}}{2^{2n-1}}\gg \sqrt{n\pi} \frac{\binom{2n-1}{n+\sqrt{n\pi}}}{2^{2n-1}}= \sqrt{n\pi}\frac{\binom{2(n+\sqrt{\pi n})-1-2\sqrt{\pi n}}{n+\sqrt{\pi n}}}{2^{2n-1}}\approx \sqrt{n\pi}\frac{\frac{{2^{2n-1}}}{\sqrt{n\pi+\pi\sqrt{\pi n}}}}{2^{2n-1}}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac\pi n}}}?$

If not what is a reasonable approximation that can be written down easily?

---

For $p=\frac12$ solution below solves.

What about $p\neq\frac12$?

I am interested in $p\geq\frac12+\frac1{2^n}$ and $p<\frac12+\frac1{2^n}$.

Comment: Did you try to approximate this by an integral?

Comment: @Wojowu I am not sure of the approximation procedure you are suggesting.

Comment: I'm with @Wojuwo on this one. Apply the central limit thoerem. The $\pi$ in the qustion is a bit of a give-away!

Comment: @ScottBurns well is my approximation reasonable?

Comment: @Wojowu is my approximation reasonable?

Comment: Sorry, no. You have no reference to $\delta$. You missed it in your first binomial expansion. Also to be honest the Gaussian approximation isn't going to give you a closed form. It will only express $\sqrt(\pi n)$ as a number of normal standard deviations

Comment: @ScottBurns corrected $\delta$ so is my approximation wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The weight $W$ (number of ones) follows a Binomial distribution with $\mu_W=(2n-1)(1/2+\delta)$ and $\sigma_W^2=(2n-1)(1/2-\delta)(1/2+\delta)$

As $n \to \infty$ this can be approximated by a gaussian $X$, with the above parameters. And the probability in question would (approximately) correspond to $P(n-\frac{1}{2} < X < n+ \sqrt  {n \pi})$. In terms of $Z$ (normalized gaussian) the limits correpond to

$$Z_1 = \frac{(n-1/2)-\mu_W}{\sqrt{\sigma_W^2}}\approx -\delta \sqrt{8n}$$

$$Z_2 = \frac{(n+\sqrt  {n \pi})-\mu_W}{\sqrt{\sigma_W^2}}\approx -\delta \sqrt{8n} + \sqrt{2 \pi}$$

Then, assuming $\delta \to 0$ fast enought (so that,eg, $\delta^2 n \to 0$) the probability area corresponds to $\sqrt{2 \pi} \approx 2.5$ (not far from the usual "three deviations" rule, so the probablity is approximately 0.5.

Comment: I do not understand how you got $1/2-\delta$

Comment: I misread the probability of one. Fixed.

Comment: so you are saying P(weight in [n,n+sqrt(n pi)]) is roughly 1/2? so my approx is wrong?

Comment: Well, your approximation implies that for large $n$ $P > 1 -\epsilon$, which does not look right...

Comment: I see the point

Comment: so the answer is $\frac12+o(1)$?

Comment: does your trick work for general $p\in(0,1)$ and not just $p=\frac12+o(1)$?

Comment: I only gave an informal approximation. A precise statement (like $\frac12+o(1)$ would require to specify how $\delta$ and $n$ tend to $0$ and $\infty$